# Backup failure for a DB part of Always-On Availability group - SQL 2012 Ent Edition

Tags: sql-server

We have a DB that we are unable to take full backups of or able to join it in AG group. The T-logs are getting succesful backups. The DB is stuck in doing a CHECKPOINT that is blocked by a DB STARTUP process. Is there anyway to clear this internal process without having to reboot? It has been sitting like this for a few days. We are able to restore the DB using the T-logs but the DB is not highly available due to not being part of the AG. We are on SQL 2012 Enterprise edition. Please don't give me an answer that I need to upgrade to latest version.

Has anyone experienced this issue in SQL 2012 or any other version when using AAG?

Comment: This is one where I'd call Microsoft for help.

Comment: I would like to see SQL Server errolog. Can you please put that on shared drive and add the link in question. And before going to MS make sure SQL Server 2012 patched to latest SP4.

Comment: We are working with MS now. I will provide the root cause analysis once they provide us one.

Answer (score 0):

MS discovered that this is an issue with 2012 CU3. We ran into this bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3033492/alwayson-availability-groups-may-be-reported-as-not-synchronizing-afte

This problem is resolved in SQL 2012 SP4.

In the interim - the solution is a reboot to get the DBs off the bad state.

Comment: "Please don't give me an answer that I need to upgrade to latest version." - That got awkward.  Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: hahaha I was hoping it was not a bug with the version :-)